# Checking each block being staged

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure-blob-storage

This is a sample of my code for uploading to Azure Blob Storage in blocks.

```
public async Task<string> UploadFiles(string connectionString, File file, string blobContainer) {

  BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(connectionString);
  BlobContainerClient containerClient = blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient(blobContainer);
  BlockBlobClient blockBlobClient = containerClient.GetBlockBlobClient(file.Name);

  using (Stream stream = file.InputStream) {

    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024 * 50];
    int bytesRead;
    int blockNumber = 0;

    while ((bytesRead = await stream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0) {
      using (MemoryStream chunkStream = new MemoryStream(buffer, 0, bytesRead)) {
        string blockId = Convert.ToBase64String(BitConverter.GetBytes(blockNumber));
        await blockBlobClient.StageBlockAsync(blockId, chunkStream);
        blockNumber++;
      }
    }

    var blockList = Enumerable.Range(0, blockNumber)
      .Select(x => Convert.ToBase64String(BitConverter.GetBytes(x)))
      .ToList();
    await blockBlobClient.CommitBlockListAsync(blockList);
  }
}
```

My question is whether or not it is possible to put in a check after staging blocks (this line: `await blockBlobClient.StageBlockAsync(blockId, chunkStream);`) to ensure that everything was staged correctly and to retry the stage if it wasn't.

My thought would be a add a check to read the staged block and if that block does not match the data in the bytes read, but I am unsure of how to do that.

**Update Question**

Instead of checking if the staged block matches the data in bytes read, how do I do the simpler task of checking if any errors/exceptions occurred from the `StageBlockAsync()` method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To check if any errors or exceptions occurred from the `StageBlockAsync` method, you can use a try-catch block to catch exceptions.We catch the `RequestFailedException` that may be thrown if an error occurs during the `StageBlockAsync` operation.AFAIK,Azure Storage Blob service does not provide a built-in mechanism to validate the content of a staged block at the time of staging. The `StageBlockAsync` method sends the data to Azure Blob Storage, and it will throw an exception if an error occurs during the upload.

[image]

```cs
static async Task<string> UploadFiles(string connectionString, Stream fileStream, string blobContainer, string blobName)
{
    // Create a BlobServiceClient
    BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(connectionString);

    // Get a BlobContainerClient
    BlobContainerClient containerClient = blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient(blobContainer);

    // Get a BlockBlobClient
    BlockBlobClient blockBlobClient = containerClient.GetBlockBlobClient(blobName);

    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024 * 50];
    int bytesRead;
    int blockNumber = 0;

    while ((bytesRead = await fileStream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
    {
        using (MemoryStream chunkStream = new MemoryStream(buffer, 0, bytesRead))
        {
            string blockId = Convert.ToBase64String(BitConverter.GetBytes(blockNumber));
            bool blockStaged = false;
            int retryCount = 0;

            while (!blockStaged && retryCount < 3) // Retry up to 3 times
            {
                try
                {
                    await blockBlobClient.StageBlockAsync(blockId, chunkStream);
                    blockStaged = true;
                }
                catch (RequestFailedException ex)
                {
                    // Handle the exception here, e.g., log it or retry staging the block.
                    Console.WriteLine($"Error staging block {blockId}: {ex.Message}");
                    retryCount++;
                    // You can implement your retry logic here if needed.
                }
            }

            if (!blockStaged)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Failed to stage block {blockId} after {retryCount} retries.");
                return null; // Indicates that the upload failed.
            }

            blockNumber++;
        }
    }

    var blockList = Enumerable.Range(0, blockNumber)
        .Select(x => Convert.ToBase64String(BitConverter.GetBytes(x)))
        .ToList();

    try
    {
        await blockBlobClient.CommitBlockListAsync(blockList);
    }
    catch (RequestFailedException ex)
    {
        // Handle the exception here, e.g., log it or take appropriate action.
        Console.WriteLine($"Error committing block list: {ex.Message}");
        // You can implement your error handling logic here.
        return null; // Indicates that the upload failed.
    }

    // The upload was successful, return the blob URI.
    return blockBlobClient.Uri.ToString();
}
```

[image]

[image]

**Another method:**

```
  public async Task<string> UploadFiles(string connectionString, Stream fileStream, string blobContainer)
  {
      BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(connectionString);
      BlobContainerClient containerClient = blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient(blobContainer);
      string blobName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(); // Use a unique name for each blob

      using (Stream stream = fileStream)
      {
          byte[] buffer = new byte[1024 * 50];
          int bytesRead;
          int blockNumber = 0;

          while ((bytesRead = await stream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
          {
              using (MemoryStream chunkStream = new MemoryStream(buffer, 0, bytesRead))
              {
                  string blockId = Convert.ToBase64String(BitConverter.GetBytes(blockNumber));

                  try
                  {
                      await containerClient.GetBlockBlobClient(blobName).StageBlockAsync(blockId, chunkStream);
                  }
                  catch (RequestFailedException ex)
                  {
                      // Handle the exception (e.g., log it)
                      Console.WriteLine($"Error staging block {blockId}: {ex.Message}");

                      
                      int retryCount = 3;
                      while (retryCount > 0)
                      {
                         
                          await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));

                          try
                          {
                              await containerClient.GetBlockBlobClient(blobName).StageBlockAsync(blockId, chunkStream);
                              break; // If the retry succeeds, exit the retry loop.
                          }
                          catch (RequestFailedException retryEx)
                          {
                              Console.WriteLine($"Retry failed: {retryEx.Message}");
                              retryCount--;
                          }
                      }

                      if (retryCount == 0)
                      {
                          // If retries are exhausted, you can throw the exception or handle it as needed.
                          throw;
                      }
                  }

                  blockNumber++;
              }
          }

          var blockList = Enumerable.Range(0, blockNumber)
            .Select(x => Convert.ToBase64String(BitConverter.GetBytes(x)))
            .ToList();

          await containerClient.GetBlockBlobClient(blobName).CommitBlockListAsync(blockList);

          return blobName; 
      }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks! I came to this conclusion too about a week ago, but forgot to update this post. Thank you for your answer.